# WEC7 web browser control not displaying page

Tags: c#, browser, windows-embedded-compact

I'm struggling with the browser control in my WEC7 application. I'm trying to display a local file in the webBrowser control, and everything appears to be working *except* that the page does not show up in the control on my form. All I see is a white rectangle where the webBrowser control is.

I made a stand-alone test app which does nothing but load a local file into the webBrowser control. I found code elsewhere on stackoverflow which seemed pretty clear. This is the code that loads the page:

```
        private void LoadPageBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string applicationDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetNam‌e().CodeBase);
                string myFile = Path.Combine(applicationDirectory, @"HTMLPage1.htm");
                Uri uri = new Uri(myFile);
                webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The file **HTMLPage1.htm** is really basic and shows up fine in any desktop browser. If I provide a bogus file name in the code then I get a *file not found* exception, so I'm pretty sure the file is being deployed correctly on the target (set to "always copy" in the file properties).

I catch the **Navigating**, **Navigated**, and **Complete** events from the webBrowser control and output some debug stuff, including the URL from the **WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs**. When the code runs I get the following debug output:

```
Navigating: file:///Program Files/webtest/HTMLPage1.htm
Complete:
```

I never see the Navigated event but I'm not sure that's a problem.

And the darn webBrowser control continued to show a white rectangle. Can anyone suggest what I may be missing?

I have posted the code here in case anyone would be kind enough to try it out themselves:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B75fBmfP8FI4YmpvYXFXcGN1Qzg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out what's going on. The answer was actually found on the Toradex support forum. The WebBrowser control is just a wrapper around IE and therefore IE needs to be included in the OS before you can use the WebBrowser in your application.

My OS build does not include the web browser components, so I'm in the process of rebuilding the OS and including all the IE7 stuff.